# × Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a select bar and then an option button inside it, but i have an error that react children can only make a single react element child. How to make a non single React element on it? thankyou.

```
<React.Fragment>
   <Form size="large" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Segment stacked>

          <Select
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            fluid
            placeholder="Please select a user">
               <option value="is_student">Student</option>
               <option value="is_teacher">Teacher</option>
          </Select>

       </Segment>
   </Form>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using that is making the issue?

Comment: sorry, the question was edited, you can see in the screenshot picture

Comment: don't do screenshots. please just put the code into the question. Also, please include any relevant code for the Select component.

Comment: I think you need to show us the <Select> element as well

Comment: you need to wrap the <option> tags inside a <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> or the shorthand <></>